# Prompting for App Store Rating directly from Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos, skstorereviewcontroller

How would you go about using the SKStoreReviewController API to prompt a user to submit a 0-5 star rating directly from the app on their Apple Watch? Is that even possible or is the prompt strictly iOS only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the StoreKit framework is available on watchOS 6.2+, SKStoreReviewController is not - just iOS and macOS at this time.

Comment: I see. But would it be possible to hard code a prompt on the watch to ask for the ratings, then transfer that to the SKStoreReviewController on the phone app?

Comment: @Jet59black No, it’s not possible to programmatically submit a response on the user’s behalf. Note the prompt isn’t guaranteed to appear when you request a review as well.